# Angular2/Firebase - orderByChild timestamp and startAt last item in array

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic2

I'm trying to do an infinite scroll feature for a list of posts that are in my database.

The first thing I do is load the last 10 posts based off of the `timestamp` and I do this using `on` as I want to load the posts as they come in:

```
this.subscription = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.userData.location)
   .orderByChild('created')
   .limitToLast(10);
   this.subscription.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
       this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val());
});
```

I don't think it's that important for the question but I thought I'd add it anyway.

Then, using Ionic and `ion-infinite-scroll` I find out if the user has reached the bottom of the content and run this function:

```
   doInfinite(event) {
       this.startLimit += 10;
        this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.userData.location)
        .orderByChild('created')
        .startAt(this.postFeed[this.postFeed.length-1].created)
        .limitToLast(this.startLimit)
        .once('value', (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach(item => {
            this.postFeed.push(item.val());
            return false;
          })
        });
    }
```

So my hope with this is that it orders by `created` (so it finds the most recent posts), starts at the last element in the arrays `created` (I also tried by key but that didn't work either) date, and then limits it to `startLimit` which starts at 10 and goes up with each infinite scroll..

The problem is, this doesn't seem to work.. it doesn't add anything to `postFeed`... Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for any help!